# Why does my bitcoin transaction has over 400 confirmations and still not in my wallet after a week now. My wallet is also correct when i cross check

Tags: transactions

I've used same wallet for multiple transactions and it's goign through but this very one is not yet in my wallet past a week now and i checked on the blockchain explorer it has more than 400 confirmations, I don't understand this!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my client not show funds that were sent to me?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/why-does-my-client-not-show-funds-that-were-sent-to-me)